# How to make a virtual video device for testing and debugging which has /dev/video9?

Tags: python, linux, bash, video-processing, vlc

I am doing a robot project, where i use 2 web camera for EYE.

I have two web camera connected to my PC in USB which creates /dev/video0 and /dev/video1, now the problem is when the camera is used by some software such as Skype or other sometimes it fails. Because the manufacturer driver for Linux itself could be the issue for making /dev/video0 or /dev/video1 disappear (unless its physically by hand unplugged and plugged back in, in some cases its not possible such as remote/robotics project, where i need 100% camera availability to use it as eye).

So to fix it i have done a script:

```
### Logitech camera lost
target="/dev/video99"
foundon="none"
warn="[WARNING]:"
ok="[OK]:"
for i in 0 1 2 3 4
do
tmp="/dev/video$i"
if [ -e $tmp ]
then
  foundon="/dev/video$i"
else
  echo "no $i"
fi
done

b="none"
if [ "$foundon" = "$b" ]
then
  echo "$warn No camera is found"
  echo "$warn Auto restarting /var/tmp/runme.sh"
  /var/tmp/runme.sh &
else
  echo "$ok ln -s $foundon $target"
  echo password | sudo -S ln -sf $foundon $target
  echo password | sudo -S chmod -R 777 $target
fi
ls /dev/vid*
```

but still its not enough, where i need to make a virtual 1 image or empty image based dummy video device interface which take a place permanently in /dev/video9 . Once i have that dummy video device i can debug/identify what cause the original camera to be lost all the time suddently.

Q. How do i make a virtual /dev/video9 which really act as a camera source showing one jpeg or video clip when any application use it as video source input? (e.g: skype or other..)

Comment: Perhaps you could configure your `udev` to use the USB ids?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I am using `v4l2loopback-dkms` . Maybe you can share how to use `udev` i could use it but i saw its very complicated and messy so did not tried. I posted the working version in my answer. How do you exactly do the same with `udev`?

Comment: Shouldn't both the "modprobe" and the "echo ... >> /etc/modules" use the same value for "video_nr=..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Works!

Step 1:

```
$ apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic

$ apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  module-assistant v4l-utils
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  v4l2loopback-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  v4l2loopback-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 506 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/24.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 115 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package v4l2loopback-dkms.
(Reading database ... 201818 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking v4l2loopback-dkms (from .../v4l2loopback-dkms_0.6.1-1_all.deb) ...
Setting up v4l2loopback-dkms (0.6.1-1) ...
Loading new v4l2loopback-0.6.1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.5.0-17-generic
Building initial module for 3.5.0-17-generic
Done.

v4l2loopback:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.

root@sun-M14xR2:~# modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=5
or
echo "v4l2loopback video_nr=0" >> /etc/modules

root@sun-M14xR2:~# v4l2-sysfs-path
Video device: video0
Video device: video3
Alsa playback device(s): hw:1,3 hw:0,0 hw:0,3
```

Step 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    target="/dev/video99"
    foundon="none"
    warn="[WARNING]:"
    ok="[OK]:"
    for i in 1 2 3 4
    do
        tmp="/dev/video$i"
        if [ -e $tmp ]
        then
          foundon="/dev/video$i"
        else
          echo "no $i"
        fi
    done

    b="none"
    if [ "$foundon" = "$b" ]
    then
        echo "$warn No camera is found"
        echo "$warn Auto restarting /var/tmp/runme.sh"
        pp=$(ps aux | grep "sink" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')
        if [ -z "$pp" ]
        then
            export DISPLAY=:0.0 && sink device=/dev/video0 &
        fi
        echo pass | sudo -S ln -sf /dev/video0 /dev/video99
        echo pass | sudo -S chmod -R 777 /dev/video99
    else
        echo "$ok ln -s $foundon $target"
        ps aux | grep "sink" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
        echo pass | sudo -S ln -sf $foundon $target
        echo pass | sudo -S chmod -R 777 $target
    fi

ls /dev/video*
sleep 1
done
```

Comment: modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=5
or
echo "v4l2loopback video_nr=0" >> /etc/modules